# Compiling gnuradio-3.8.0.0 with gnuradio-companion support

Tags: gnuradio, gnuradio-companion

gnuradio-companion works fine for me with gnuradio-3.7.13.4, but fails to be selected when configuring gnuradio-3.8.0.0 for compilation.  When configuring gnuradio-3.8.0.0, cmake reports this:

```
-- ######################################################
-- # Gnuradio enabled components                         
-- ######################################################
--   * python-support
--   * testing-support
--   * volk
--   * doxygen
--   * gnuradio-runtime
--   * gr-ctrlport
--   * gr-blocks
--   * gr-fec
--   * gr-fft
--   * gr-filter
--   * gr-analog
--   * gr-digital
--   * gr-dtv
--   * gr-audio
--   * * alsa
--   * * oss
--   * * portaudio
--   * gr-channels
--   * gr-qtgui
--   * gr-trellis
--   * gr-utils
--   * gr-video-sdl
--   * gr-vocoder
--   * gr-wavelet
-- 
-- ######################################################
-- # Gnuradio disabled components                        
-- ######################################################
--   * sphinx
--   * gnuradio-companion
--   * gr-uhd
--   * gr_modtool
--   * gr-zeromq
```

Presumably gnuradio-companion now has an additional dependency.  Can anyone help with what that might be?

**Edit**: the missing dependency was PyYAML.  With that installed gnuradio-companion compiles and seems to work OK.

Comment: Dependency version bumps: CMake, GCC, MSVC, Swig, Boost
New dependencies: MPIR/GMP, Qt5, gsm, codec2
Removed dependencies: libusb, Qt4, CppUnit

Comment: I saw that.  The dependencies are met apart from gsm and codec2, which surely are not required for gnuradio-companion.  There are other new dependencies I have detected such as log4cpp, but there must be some other one affecting gnuradio-companion.  Any idea what?

Comment: Looks as if the missing new dependency may be PyYAML.  Further testing required.

Comment: the interesting part of the CMake run is missing. Just a couple lines above, CMake tells you *why* it disabled these components.